# What path do I need to prevent 404 on Swagger api-docs?

Tags: spring, http-status-code-404, swagger

I am trying to navigate to my api-docs generated by the project and I consistently get 404's on /api-docs and I was hoping someone might have some more insight as to why.I think it might have something to do with setting up the path to the /api-docs endpoint but I'm unsure
Here are some of the files that I thought would be necessary in debugging the issue. Also, i've replaced a few names with the string "example" on purpose for this post. they arent actually in the project as so.

Server Logs:
localhost.2015-07-20.log

```
20-Jul-2015 13:53:43.185 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
20-Jul-2015 13:53:43.683 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
20-Jul-2015 13:53:44.710 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'appServlet'
20-Jul-2015 13:54:04.047 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Destroying Spring FrameworkServlet 'appServlet'
20-Jul-2015 13:54:04.067 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
```

localhost_access_log..2015-07-20.txt

```
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [20/Jul/2015:13:50:50 -0500] "GET /examplelocations/api-docs HTTP/1.1" 404 1050
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [20/Jul/2015:13:51:58 -0500] "GET /examplelocations/api-docs HTTP/1.1" 404 1050
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Jul/2015:13:51:58 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2718
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [20/Jul/2015:13:53:50 -0500] "GET /examplelocations/api-docs HTTP/1.1" 404 1050
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Jul/2015:13:53:50 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2718
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Swagger Servlet --><!-- new -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>DefaultJaxrsConfig</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.config.DefaultJaxrsConfig</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>api.version</param-name>
            <param-value>0.0</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>swagger.api.basepath</param-name>
            <param-value>http://localhost:8080/examplelocations/api-docs</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <resource-env-ref>
      <description>
        Object Factory for Locations Database Settings
      </description>
      <resource-env-ref-name>
        locationsdatabase
      </resource-env-ref-name>
      <resource-env-ref-type>
        com.example.examplelocations.domain.DBContextBean
      </resource-env-ref-type>
    </resource-env-ref>

    <resource-env-ref>
      <description>
        Object Factory for Google Lookup Settings
      </description>
      <resource-env-ref-name>
        googlelookup
      </resource-env-ref-name>
      <resource-env-ref-type>
        com.example.examplelocations.domain.GoogleLookupContextBean
      </resource-env-ref-type>
    </resource-env-ref>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>SimpleCORSFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.example.examplelocations.servletfilters.SimpleCORSFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>SimpleCORSFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

a portion of the pom.xml file

```
<!-- Swagger -->
 <dependency>
     <groupId>com.mangofactory</groupId>
     <artifactId>swagger-springmvc</artifactId>
     <version>1.0.2</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
     <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
     <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs_2.10</artifactId>
 <version>1.3.12</version>
 </dependency>
 <!-- Swagger WebJar -->
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
     <artifactId>swagger-ui</artifactId>
     <version>2.0.24</version>
 </dependency>
```

servlet-context.xml (portion):

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.examplelocations" />
<annotation-driven />
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/swagger.properties" />
```

swagger.properties

```
documentation.services.basePath=http://localhost:8080/examplelocations
documentation.services.version=1.0.2
```

If there is a need for anymore information please let me know and I'll do my best to supply it.

Comment: You've integrated an old version of swagger-core. Please use the latest - https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-Core-JAX-RS-Project-Setup-1.5.X.